# How to dynamically fill empty space in a column

Tags: html, css, asp.net, tabular

I have a table with three columns. The content of column 1 is dynamic. It's a schedule for the day so every day the length of text changes. Column 2 is also dynamic but does not change as frequently maybe a few times a month. Column 3 is static, I change the information manually.

The problem is that every day one of the columns could have empty space. On any given day column 1 could be longer or shorter then the other two columns. What I want to do is dynamically fill the empty space no matter which column needs it so that all three are somewhat balanced looking.

The text in each column has a div wrapper. My thought is another div at the end of each column that could be filled with text or an image and would automatically shrink or grow depending on the overall height of the table.

I've searched different HTML/CSS properties but haven't found a solution yet. Maybe I'm asking too much but hoping someone has done something similar to this. Most news sites seem to do this well even within sections. Their columns look balanced.

I don't know how this would work server side as it needs to know the final height but if you do have a solution that way I use VB but also Javascript if client side. But I'd think there would be a CSS way.

EDIT: I'm referring to the HEIGHT of the column only, column widths are fixed. Searching google all I could get were solutions for width too so maybe what I'm asking for can't or hasn't been done. I'm referring to the amount of text that fills up the HEIGHT of the column. For simplicity lets say column 1 is the only one that changes. But the amount of text that fills the HEIGHT of column 1 could be more or less than what fills up the other two columns leaving a blank area either in column 1 if it has less text or a blank area in the other two columns if it has more text than either of the other two. Hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Add class on td in first column with min-width, for example.
`td.myclass {min-width: 100px;}` In this way you dont add empty space in tb, but you don't have td too small.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm actually referring to the height of each column. The widths are set.

Comment: Sorry or the misunderstanding but for table you mean HTML <table>?

Comment: No problem. When I was searching the results that came back were about width as well. Yes I'm referring to the HTML Table. I know the argument divs are preferred but in this case the table works best. In fact, it really should work well for what I'm trying to do because the overall height of each column is set the same.

Comment: Tag <table> is perfect for table :) anyway in an HTML table the height of column can't change unless missing td

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying what you want the remainder of the columns to be filled with, so I'm assuming that they can be just random images.
In that case, the solution is to assign a background image to each `td` and to give the divs inside a solid background. That way, the height of the table is just its natural height (the height of the largest text) and no extra tricks are necessary.

```css
body {background:#FFE}
table {
  border: 1px outset gray
}
td {
  border: 1px inset gray;
  width: 33.3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
}
td:first-child {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/900) repeat;
}
td:first-child + td {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/901) repeat;
}
td:first-child + td + td {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/902) repeat;
}
td > div {
  background: #FFE;
  padding: .33em
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Like a news web site. If you look at news websites their columns always seem to come out even at the bottom. 

It could be a little bit of text with more... link or something to make the columns look balanced. 

Your sample looks like the image repeats if the column grows.

Comment: A "Read more" link? No sorry, that wasn't clear at all from the question. I thought you wanted to fill up the remainder of the cell with something, if the contents aren't the same height. But if you include "read more" links, it's your decision to show as much of the text as you want. I.e. you decide how high the columns will be; so there is no "left over" space.

Comment: By the way, if you want a non-repeating image, just use a bigger image!

Comment: The empty space is dynamic. Column 1 changes everyday, column 2 at least once a week, column 3 less possibly static for over a month. The empty space will always be different and depending on how much information is in each column could make it the tallest column at any time. 
Doesn't matter if there's a read more link or not but preferably text, something that provides information which a partial image just fills space.